# throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

i tried to upload product (including the image), i used the same code on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCmjLIEtJbA&t=206s, but its failed to upload product ?, but the server give me a 200 res, then the express app goes crash, could you help me with this issues ??

this is my UploadPage component (React) :

```
const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // send data to server
    const variables = {
      writer: props.user.userData._id,
      title: TitleValue,
      description: DescriptionValue,
      price: PriceValue,
      images: Images,
      continents: ContinentValue,
    };

    Axios.post("/api/product/uploadProduct", variables).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.success) {
        alert("Successfully to upload product");
        props.history.push("/");
      } else {
        alert("Failed to upload product");
      }
    });
  };
```

and here for the product route (Express) :

```
router.post("/uploadProduct", auth, (req, res) => {
  // save all data from the client to database

  const product = new Product(req.body);

  product.save((err) => {
    // if fail
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ success: false, err });
    }

    // if success
    return res.json(200).json({ success: true });
  });
});
```

here's also my FileUpload component (React) :

```
const onDrop = (files) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    const config = {
      header: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    };

    formData.append("file", files[0]);

    // save the image inside the node server
    Axios.post("/api/product/uploadImage", formData, config).then(
      (response) => {
        if (response.data.success) {
          setImages([...Images, response.data.image]);

          props.refreshFunction([...Images, response.data.image]);
        } else {
          alert("Failed to save the Image in server");
        }
      }
    );
  };
```

did the front end messed up the back end ?,

Thanks, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You can check in your `auth` middleware, make sure, when you use the `res`, then add `return` before `res`.

Comment: Somewhere is your backend code, you are calling `return res.sen...` after you've sent a response to the client

Comment: @ChristianLisangola thanks for the advice bro, i already solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself, somewhere in my (Express) code there is a code like this:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  // where i want to save the file
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  // more code
});
```

then i change it into :

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  // where i want to save the file
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./uploads/");
  },
  // more code
});
```